# Numbered/Ordered List In Microsoft Visio 2013?

Tags: microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

Microsoft Visio 2013 seems to support bulleted/unordered lists, but what about creating numbered/ordered lists?

Specifically, I have placed a Text container onto a page and want to add a numbered/ordered list.

Note: As a workaround, copy/paste suffices, from Microsoft Word, and so forth...but would be nice if Visio natively supports this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What about creating numbered/ordered lists?

Follow the instructions below.

**Office 2007**

> **Create a numbered list**
>
> 1. Double-click a shape.
>
>    If you don't see the text-editing ruler, right-click the shape, and then click "Text Ruler".
> 2. Right-click the shape, and then click "Format Text". Click the "Paragraph" tab, and then in the "Alignment list", click the alignment you
>      want, and then click "OK".
> 3. Type the number for the first list item, press <kbd>Tab</kbd>, type the text you want, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Repeat this for each list
>      item you want.
> 4. Select all of the list items.
> 5. On the text-editing ruler, drag the bottom of the hourglass Right indent market of text-editing ruler until it's in the position
>      you want the text (not the numbers) to align.
> 6. On the text-editing ruler, drag the top of the hourglass First line indent marker of text-editing ruler until it's in the position
>      you want the numbers to align.
> 7. Click outside the shape to close the text-editing ruler.

Source [Create numbered or bulleted lists inside a shape - Visio](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-numbered-or-bulleted-lists-inside-a-shape-251e16b9-2478-4a6e-b866-d1273212c569#ID0EAABAAA=Office_2007)

**Newer Versions**

> Create a numbered list
>
> 1. Double-click a shape. The shape appears in edit mode with the Text Ruler above it.
>
>    Note: If you don't see the text-editing ruler, right-click the shape, and then click Text Ruler.
>
>    [image: Text Ruler]
> 2. Right-click the shape, and then click Paragraph. Now in the Paragraph tab, in the Alignment list, click the alignment you want,
>      and then click OK.
> 3. Type the number for the first list item, press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, type the text you want, and then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Repeat this step to add a new
>      numbered step to the list.
> 4. Select all of the list items.
> 5. On the text-editing ruler, drag the bottom of the hourglass until it's in the position you want the text (not the numbers) to
>      align.
> 6. On the text-editing ruler, drag the top of the hourglass until it's in the position you want the numbers to align.
> 7. Click outside the shape to close the text-editing ruler.

Source [Create numbered or bulleted lists inside a shape - Visio](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-numbered-or-bulleted-lists-inside-a-shape-251e16b9-2478-4a6e-b866-d1273212c569#ID0EAABAAA=Newer_versions)

Comment: I appreciate the answer, David; thank you. It's a bit clunky, in my opinion, but it comes straight from Microsoft, so that seems to represent the official solution, for now. Note: I'm new to using the Text Ruler, so I struggled with finding it, in Microsoft Visio 2013...I discovered it after entering "edit mode" for the text, then right-clicking and selecting it from the popup menu. Thanks again.

Comment: There is no "Format text" for me... It seems that [MS help](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-numbered-or-bulleted-lists-inside-a-shape-251e16b9-2478-4a6e-b866-d1273212c569) differs from the contents of this answer.. Maybe it was updated..

Comment: @gsamaras Updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

The **short answer** is that your idea to **copy a numbered list from Miscroft Word**  seems to be the best answer.  Microsoft implies that *numbered lists are not able to be generated from Visio* -- they essentially say "make your numbers manually, and we'll, uh, align the items for you".

David's answer (which is all you get from Microsoft) is a fine way to get the **alignment to be automatic** (alignment of numbers you typed in vs. text items) -- but that procedure still asks you to manually create each item's number for list.  These numbers you typed won't update automatically if you insert an item into the middle of the list, like it does in Word's numbered lists.  And that alignment is mostly only helpful if you have more than 9 items in your list, since items 10+ shift things by another character.

For me, if I was not getting the automatic re-numbering anyway, it was faster to **do it all manually:** type the number and align it myself using tabs or spaces if desired.

But your method of copying the list from Word works better.  **Updating the list** with new items, once inside of Visio, still don't auto-number for me.  But I can paste it back into Word, highlight it all and click on the numbered list button again; and then it is ready to be updated automatically again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also embed a Microsoft Word Document via Insert->Object. It's a bit heavyweight, but you can edit the list using Word. For styling you can drop it inside a Visio element.